# Invalid Color Argument in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to fill the window with this background and I'm getting an 'invalid color argument' error. This confuses me because there isn't anything stating a color value (besides the picture, but I've changed that three times, so I don't believe that is the issue).

Code:

```
win.fill(pygame.image.load('Background/Yellow.png').convert()) 
if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
    walkCount = 0
    
if left:  
    win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (x,y))
    walkCount += 1                          
elif right:
    win.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x,y))
    walkCount += 1
elif idle:
    win.blit(char1, (x, y))
    walkCount = 0
    
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: When you ask your next question, please provide the full traceback (error message). This will make it easier for us to find the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot [`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) a window with a background image, however you can [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the background:

```py
background = pygame.image.load('Background/Yellow.png').convert()
```

```py
win.blit(background, (0, 0))
```

If the background is a different size than the window, you need to scale the background image with [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale):

```py
background = pygame.image.load('Background/Yellow.png').convert()
scaled_background = pygame.transform.smoothscale(background, win.get_size())
```

```py
win.blit(scaled_background, (0, 0))
```